Issue with 'this' variable inside route.js when more than 1 steps are executed
I have a function inside route.js that takes parameter values from feature file and append the api url.
Problem is I have more than 1 entries in 'Example' table in feature file, so the steps are executed in  pipeline.
First time when the steps are run, the path variable inside route.js append function is correct.
Next time when it runs, the previous value of 'this' variable stays and then new value append on top of it. which makes it as a issue.
Route.js

import { route } from xxxx;

class ABC extends Route {
constructor() {
       super();
       this.path = apiUrl,
}
append(var1,var2) {
this.path = this.path + var1 + var2;
}
}

export new ABC Object;

Feature File:
Given I execute <var1> and <var2>
Examples:
var1 | var2
abc | def
xyz | hij

1st step execution: console.log(this.path) // apiUrlabcdef
2nd step execution: console.log(this.path) // apiUrlabcdefxyzhij

I want the 2nd step this.path to be apiUrlxyzhij for correct api request. 


import { route } from 'xxxx';

class ABC extends Route {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.basePath = apiUrl; 
        this.path = this.basePath;
    }

    append(var1, var2) {
        this.path = this.basePath; 
        this.path += var1 + var2;
    }
}

export new ABC();

for each execution, this.path will be reset and will not retain the appended value from the previous execution, thus ensuring the correct URL for each API request :
